# Bake LuaSQL into luatex binary on Windows

Tags: luatex, windows, lua, database

Further to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337664/how-to-install-luasql-for-lualatex-on-windows-with-miktex), I want to build **luatex** on Windows with the **LuaSQL** library baked in, at least with the ODBC drivers.

[This post](http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2010-July/001712.html) by Taco Hoekwater back in 2010 walks through the process for baking in **luaxml-reader** but it appears that the make/configure/build environment for luatex has moved on since then, making it challenging to apply his technique.

I am no automake guru, but I have got as far as being able to successfully build luatex.exe with MinGW, so I feel pretty close!

I am hoping that the results of my efforts will enable access to databases via ODBC directly from within LuaLaTeX documents. Given the existing issues with accessing lua libraries from luatex (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65562/accessing-other-lua-libraries-in-lualatex-miktex) for example), I think a bespoke bake is the most viable option.

Comment: I think that the most difficult thing is how to get Lua C modules to compile on Windows, I've tried that with `Harfbuzz` and ended with total frustration. It's possible that things might be easier with the new Ubuntu subsystem in Windows 10, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: [swiglib](http://www.luatex.org/swiglib.html) may be of interest here but I'm far from being an expert on that matter.

Comment: After a long battle, I've managed to compile the [luasql-odbc](https://luarocks.org/modules/luarocks/luasql-odbcc) module with both Visual Studio 2015 and MinGW. Agreed, it was painful, but it works and I can access ODBC databases from the installation of lua (5.1 or 5.2) against which it was built. But that is a far cry from building it against the version of lua built into MikTeX...

Comment: @dsla in this case you can install the library somewhere `luatex` can see it. You can list these directories using `package.cpath`.

Comment: @michal.h21 I wish it were so simple. I can find the dll, and even access it from lualatex with `driver = package.loadlib("odbc.dll","luaopen_luasql_odbc")` but this raises an error `multiple Lua VMs detected` which is how I got to where I am now... (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213559/lua5-2s-error-multiple-lua-vms-detected) for example.)

Comment: @dsla it seems like some Windows speciality. I had issues on Linux that Lua 5.3 is used on my system, but LuaTeX uses Lua 5.2. I ended with Lua 5.2 installed in Docker container, just to compile libraries. Anyway, I guess the issue in your case is something different, which I can't really help with :(